# Where to get the X in Z-score Normal Distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

(A) Find the 95th percentile of a normal distribution with mean 100 and standard deviation 20.

---

So Z = $\frac {X- \mu}{\sigma}$. And were given $\mu$ and $\sigma$, so I'm assuming X is 95? If I take this as X,I get Z = -0.25, and from looking at a table the 95th quantile would be 0.4013. Am I thinking about this right?

---

(B) Find the 25th percentile of a normal distribution with mean 10.5 and variance 65.

---

Is the X here just 25/10.5?

Comment: A) You can find $Z$ by looking in the table for the $Z$ corresponding to $0.95$.  Now, you will know $Z,\mu$ and $\sigma$ so manipulate the formula you have $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ to solve for $X$

Comment: @JMoravitz Is finding X finding the 95th percentile?

Comment: If the book write capital letter $X$, it usually means a random variable, and it follows the normal distribution mentioned in this question (and $Z$ follows the standard normal distribution). Of course since this is a  location-scale transform which is monotonic, and we have $\sigma > 0$ which preserve the direction, so the corresponding quantiles of $Z$ and $X$ also satisfy this relationship.

Comment: When something asks you to "Find the 90th percentile" like this, it is usually asking reworded "What value of $x$ is such that $90\%$ of the data lies less than the value of $x$ and $10\%$ of the data lies above the value of $x$."  Here, we have a normal distribution with mean 100 and standard deviation 20., so a good many of the values we expect to see will lie in the 60-140 range.  We ask what value $x$ is it so that $95\%$ of the time a randomly picked value from that distribution is less than $x$ and $5\%$ of the time it is more than $x$.  $0.4013$ is definitely too small.

Comment: @JMoravitz So in the case for A, the z-score for 0.95 is 1.65. So X = $Z \sigma + \mu = (1.65)(20) + 100 = 133$. I do the same for B?

Comment: Exactly.  That is correct.  Be mindful of phrasing for the question as well, sometimes we are looking for 95% of values lying lower than, whereas in some cases we are interested in 95% of values lying *above* instead.  Without additional context, the former is usually what is intended.

Answer (score 0):

$\bbox[pink,0.25ex]X$ is the random variable of interest and $\bbox[pink, 0.25ex]x$ is the unknown value you wish to find.

$X$ is presumed to be normally distributed with mean $\bbox[pink,0.25ex]\mu$ and variance $\bbox[pink,0.25ex]{\sigma^2}$.   So we use the following : where $Z$ is a normally distributed random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1^2$, then:

$$\mathsf P(X\leq x) ~=~ \mathsf P(Z\leq \dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$$

Now a value $\bbox[pink,0.25ex]\alpha$ for any $\bbox[pink,0.25ex]p$ (eg $p=0.95$, or $p=0.25$, *et cetera*) in $~\bbox[pink,0.25ex]{\mathsf P(Z\leq \alpha)= p}~$ can be found by looking up your Student's $Z$ tables.   (So named as they were published by a mathematician using the alias "Student").

When you have found $\alpha$ from the tables, then clearly $\bbox[pink,0.25ex]{x = \alpha\sigma+\mu}$ gives you the value you really want.